# crash report EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) ios IPad 10.3.3

Tags: ios, xamarin, crash-reports

Apple informed us that our app has some problems. I tried to read the crashlog but can't understand anything. When I run the app on my device (IPad) I get no errors and everything is working fine.

Is it because we got only a developer IPad? How can I find out why Apple got a crash?

I got the following crash log back:

```
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.3 (14G60)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  tid_403  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000189e75014 0x189e56000 + 126996
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3f264 0x189f3a000 + 21092
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000189de99c4 0x189d88000 + 399812
3   DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101f793c0 0x100020000 + 32871360
4   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x0000000189f3931c 0x189f33000 + 25372
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3f264 0x189f3a000 + 21092
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000189de99c4 0x189d88000 + 399812
7   DWA.iOS                         0x0000000102078a78 0x100020000 + 33917560
8   DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101fb5220 0x100020000 + 33116704
9   DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101f78ffc 0x100020000 + 32870396
10  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101f7809c 0x100020000 + 32866460
11  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101f70a70 0x100020000 + 32836208
12  DWA.iOS                         0x000000010032ded8 0x100020000 + 3202776
13  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000100dd5e88 0x100020000 + 14376584
14  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000100dd58ac 0x100020000 + 14375084
15  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000100dd4cd0 0x100020000 + 14372048
16  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000100dd4a9c 0x100020000 + 14371484
17  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000100048b10 0x100020000 + 166672
18  DWA.iOS                         0x00000001002fc1b4 0x100020000 + 2998708
19  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101f86628 0x100020000 + 32925224
20  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101febb10 0x100020000 + 33340176
21  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101feba70 0x100020000 + 33340016
22  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000100027260 0x100020000 + 29280
23  DWA.iOS                         0x00000001000277fc 0x100020000 + 30716
24  UIKit                           0x0000000191016e48 0x190f96000 + 527944
25  UIKit                           0x000000019122337c 0x190f96000 + 2675580
26  UIKit                           0x0000000191228e24 0x190f96000 + 2698788
27  UIKit                           0x000000019123d8b0 0x190f96000 + 2783408
28  UIKit                           0x00000001912260b8 0x190f96000 + 2687160
29  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018ca24884 0x18c9ea000 + 239748
30  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018ca246f0 0x18c9ea000 + 239344
31  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018ca24aa0 0x18c9ea000 + 240288
32  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ae2942c 0x18ad4e000 + 898092
33  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ae28d9c 0x18ad4e000 + 896412
34  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ae269a8 0x18ad4e000 + 887208
35  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ad56da4 0x18ad4e000 + 36260
36  UIKit                           0x000000019100ffc8 0x190f96000 + 499656
37  UIKit                           0x000000019100ac9c 0x190f96000 + 478364
38  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000100b7a7a0 0x100020000 + 11904928
39  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000100b1a15c 0x100020000 + 11510108
40  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000100b1a11c 0x100020000 + 11510044
41  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000100048aa4 0x100020000 + 166564
42  DWA.iOS                         0x00000001002fc1b4 0x100020000 + 2998708
43  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101f86628 0x100020000 + 32925224
44  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101febb10 0x100020000 + 33340176
45  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101fee4dc 0x100020000 + 33350876
46  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101f70280 0x100020000 + 32834176
47  DWA.iOS                         0x000000010207ca2c 0x100020000 + 33933868
48  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000100045e74 0x100020000 + 155252
49  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000189d6559c 0x189d61000 + 17820

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000189e75a88 0x189e56000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3b1a4 0x189f3a000 + 4516
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3acac 0x189f3a000 + 3244

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000189e75a88 0x189e56000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3b1a4 0x189f3a000 + 4516
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3acac 0x189f3a000 + 3244

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000189e75a88 0x189e56000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3afd0 0x189f3a000 + 4048
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3acac 0x189f3a000 + 3244

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000189e74e1c 0x189e56000 + 126492
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3c814 0x189f3a000 + 10260
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x0000000189865ac8 0x18985e000 + 31432
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018f703f08 0x18ed4a000 + 10198792
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018f703e7c 0x18ed4a000 + 10198652
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018f703d5c 0x18ed4a000 + 10198364
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018f70400c 0x18ed4a000 + 10199052
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3d68c 0x189f3a000 + 13964
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3d59c 0x189f3a000 + 13724
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3acb4 0x189f3a000 + 3252

Thread 5 name:  WebThread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000189e57224 0x189e56000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000189e5709c 0x189e56000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ae28e90 0x18ad4e000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ae26ae4 0x18ad4e000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ad56da4 0x18ad4e000 + 36260
5   WebCore                         0x000000018fa21d3c 0x18f9df000 + 273724
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3d68c 0x189f3a000 + 13964
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3d59c 0x189f3a000 + 13724
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3acb4 0x189f3a000 + 3252

Thread 6 name:  SGen worker
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000189e74e1c 0x189e56000 + 126492
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3c814 0x189f3a000 + 10260
2   DWA.iOS                         0x00000001020598bc 0x100020000 + 33790140
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3d68c 0x189f3a000 + 13964
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3d59c 0x189f3a000 + 13724
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3acb4 0x189f3a000 + 3252

Thread 7 name:  Finalizer
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000189e57260 0x189e56000 + 4704
1   DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101fb6358 0x100020000 + 33121112
2   DWA.iOS                         0x000000010200fa28 0x100020000 + 33487400
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3d68c 0x189f3a000 + 13964
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3d59c 0x189f3a000 + 13724
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3acb4 0x189f3a000 + 3252

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3aca8 0x189f3a000 + 3240

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000189e57224 0x189e56000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000189e5709c 0x189e56000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ae28e90 0x18ad4e000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ae26ae4 0x18ad4e000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ad56da4 0x18ad4e000 + 36260
5   Foundation                      0x000000018b871db4 0x18b865000 + 52660
6   Foundation                      0x000000018b892b84 0x18b865000 + 187268
7   UIKit                           0x0000000191994830 0x190f96000 + 10479664
8   Foundation                      0x000000018b96f318 0x18b865000 + 1090328
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3d68c 0x189f3a000 + 13964
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3d59c 0x189f3a000 + 13724
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3acb4 0x189f3a000 + 3252

Thread 10 name:  tid_7d03
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000189e74e1c 0x189e56000 + 126492
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3c814 0x189f3a000 + 10260
2   DWA.iOS                         0x000000010206c6ac 0x100020000 + 33867436
3   DWA.iOS                         0x0000000102008030 0x100020000 + 33456176
4   DWA.iOS                         0x000000010200fa28 0x100020000 + 33487400
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3d68c 0x189f3a000 + 13964
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3d59c 0x189f3a000 + 13724
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3acb4 0x189f3a000 + 3252

Thread 11 name:  Threadpool worker
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000189e74e1c 0x189e56000 + 126492
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3c814 0x189f3a000 + 10260
2   DWA.iOS                         0x0000000102008618 0x100020000 + 33457688
3   DWA.iOS                         0x000000010200fa28 0x100020000 + 33487400
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3d68c 0x189f3a000 + 13964
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3d59c 0x189f3a000 + 13724
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3acb4 0x189f3a000 + 3252

Thread 12 name:  Threadpool worker
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000189e74e1c 0x189e56000 + 126492
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3c814 0x189f3a000 + 10260
2   DWA.iOS                         0x0000000102008618 0x100020000 + 33457688
3   DWA.iOS                         0x000000010200fa28 0x100020000 + 33487400
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3d68c 0x189f3a000 + 13964
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3d59c 0x189f3a000 + 13724
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3acb4 0x189f3a000 + 3252

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000022
    x4: 0x000000000000001b   x5: 0x000000016fddabc0   x6: 0x0000000000000031   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x0000000000003fff
   x12: 0x0000000125f24000  x13: 0x00000000000030df  x14: 0x00000000000030df  x15: 0x00000000000030df
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x000000018ad75c10  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001b08e4b40  x21: 0x000000010208f490  x22: 0x000000010208f4d8  x23: 0x000000016fddafa8
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000126a92578  x26: 0x0000000125e00730  x27: 0x000000012700aa00
   x28: 0x0000000127014ca8   fp: 0x000000016fddaf40   lr: 0x0000000189f3f264
    sp: 0x000000016fddaf20   pc: 0x0000000189e75014 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

EDIT:
Heres the Code in my AppDelegate.cs:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            DevExpress.Mobile.Forms.Init();

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

            LoadApplication(new App());


            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
```

EDIT 2: After symbolicate:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  tid_403  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000189e75014 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3f264 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000189de99c4 abort + 140
3   DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101f793c0 0x100020000 + 32871360
4   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x0000000189f3931c _sigtramp + 52
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f3f264 pthread_kill + 112
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000189de99c4 abort + 140
7   DWA.iOS                         0x0000000102078a78 0x100020000 + 33917560
8   DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101fb5220 0x100020000 + 33116704
9   DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101f78ffc 0x100020000 + 32870396
10  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101f7809c 0x100020000 + 32866460
11  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101f70a70 0x100020000 + 32836208
12  DWA.iOS                         0x000000010032ded8 0x100020000 + 3202776
13  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000100dd5e88 0x100020000 + 14376584
14  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000100dd58ac 0x100020000 + 14375084
15  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000100dd4cd0 0x100020000 + 14372048
16  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000100dd4a9c 0x100020000 + 14371484
17  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000100048b10 0x100020000 + 166672
18  DWA.iOS                         0x00000001002fc1b4 0x100020000 + 2998708
19  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101f86628 0x100020000 + 32925224
20  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101febb10 0x100020000 + 33340176
21  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101feba70 0x100020000 + 33340016
22  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000100027260 0x100020000 + 29280
23  DWA.iOS                         0x00000001000277fc 0x100020000 + 30716
24  UIKit                           0x0000000191016e48 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 380
25  UIKit                           0x000000019122337c -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3452
26  UIKit                           0x0000000191228e24 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1684
27  UIKit                           0x000000019123d8b0 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.3147 + 48
28  UIKit                           0x00000001912260b8 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 168
29  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018ca24884 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
30  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018ca246f0 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 176
31  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018ca24aa0 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
32  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ae2942c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
33  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ae28d9c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
34  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ae269a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 744
35  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ad56da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
36  UIKit                           0x000000019100ffc8 -[UIApplication _run] + 652
37  UIKit                           0x000000019100ac9c UIApplicationMain + 208
38  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000100b7a7a0 0x100020000 + 11904928
39  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000100b1a15c 0x100020000 + 11510108
40  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000100b1a11c 0x100020000 + 11510044
41  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000100048aa4 0x100020000 + 166564
42  DWA.iOS                         0x00000001002fc1b4 0x100020000 + 2998708
43  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101f86628 0x100020000 + 32925224
44  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101febb10 0x100020000 + 33340176
45  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101fee4dc 0x100020000 + 33350876
46  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000101f70280 0x100020000 + 32834176
47  DWA.iOS                         0x000000010207ca2c 0x100020000 + 33933868
48  DWA.iOS                         0x0000000100045e74 0x100020000 + 155252
49  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000189d6559c start + 4
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post if there is any code you are using in app delegate?

Comment: After starting the App we go into an Registration. Apple was able to do that too. After complete the Registration the App crashes at Apple side.

Yeah i got Code in AppDelegate.cs

When we start the App we read the Device ID. Can that be the Problem ?

Comment: Do you use system date(Date()) in App Delegate ?

Comment: No, i Init Devexpress and Xamarin.forms and set securityprotocol.
That is all

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash report.

Comment: I edited my whole question and added the symbolicate Report.
But i dont understand where the error occurs.

Comment: The symbolicated report is missing the symbols for your apps frames. And those are the important frames. This is not fully symbolicated.

Comment: How can I do it with the Symbols for my app Frames?

Comment: What tools did you use to build this app?

Comment: Which Tools do you mean? I use Visual Studio 2017 and created an IPA-File which i loaded up to Apple

Comment: @Pascal You need to use the *.dSYM from the build that you uploaded to properly symbolicate that crash so you can get the  the files/linenumbers http://jmillerdev.net/symbolicating-ios-crash-files-xamarin-ios/